# Poisions that aren't detected in usual autopsies & mimics cardiac issues

Tags: poisons

Doing some research for a short piece I'm writing where a character murders their husband. This husband has heart problems and the idea is to make his death look like a heart attack or something similar. Poisons are preferable but if there's other ideas I would be open to them. Im aware of SUX and how it can either make it look like asphyxiation or cardiac arrest but this character would be a bit too careful to risk the look of asphyxiation. I'm also aware of the air bubble in a vein trick, but I'm unsure if this is a myth or not. So if anyone could link articles regarding it that would also be lovely!

Comment: It is possible to put enough air in a vein to kill somebody (so I've been told), but a normal bubble won't do it.

Comment: Potassium. A doctor killed his wife this way.

Answer (score 1):

**Viagra.**

And sex.  The wife gets him viagra and he can have an erection for the first time in years.  Then he dies from the cardiac demands of the sex he can finally have.

https://www.forhims.com/blog/can-viagra-cause-a-heart-attack

> Viagra is a vasodilator, meaning it helps open up blood vessels and
> arteries. That being said, there have been reports of heart attack,
> stroke, arrhythmia and even death in men taking Viagra.
>
> Some experts cite the results of a 2002 study to support the theory
> that heart attacks linked to Viagra  were more likely related to the
> performance of sexual activity (specifically in patients with coronary
> artery disease) than to the use of the drug.

I submit this in the interest of the needs of your story because I am that helpful kind of person.  Also, if you are a would-be murderer shopping for ideas on how to murder someone in real life, if you use this technique maybe the some-one won't mind so much.  It is a good way to go.